# SQL Query to return rows where a list of numbers is between start and end values

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a table in Oracle with the columns:

```
id | start_number | end_number
---+--------------+------------
1  | 100          | 200
2  | 151          | 200
3  | 25           | 49
4  | 98           | 99  
5  | 49           | 100
```

There is a list of numbers (50, 99, 150).

I want an sql statement that returns all the ids where any of the numbers in the list of numbers is found equal to or between the start_number and the end_number.

Using the above example; 1, 4 and 5 should be returned.
1 - 150 is between or equal to 100 and 200
2 - none of the numbers are between or equal to 151 and 200
3 - none of the numbers are between or equal to 25 and 49
4 - 99 is between or equal to 98 and 99
5 - 50 and 99 are between or equal to 49 and 100

```
drop table TEMP_TABLE;

create table TEMP_TABLE(
THE_ID number,
THE_START number,
THE_END number
);

insert into TEMP_TABLE(THE_ID, THE_START, THE_END) values (1, 100, 200);
insert into TEMP_TABLE(THE_ID, THE_START, THE_END) values (2, 151, 200);
insert into TEMP_TABLE(THE_ID, THE_START, THE_END) values (3, 25, 49);
insert into TEMP_TABLE(THE_ID, THE_START, THE_END) values (4, 98, 99);
insert into TEMP_TABLE(the_id, the_start, the_end) values (5, 49, 100);
```

The following is the solution I came up with based on the comments and answers below plus some additional research:

```
SELECT
*
from
TEMP_TABLE
where
EXISTS (select * from(
select column_value as id 
from table(SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL(50,99,150)) 
)
where id
BETWEEN TEMP_TABLE.the_start AND TEMP_TABLE.the_end
)
```

This works too:

```
SELECT
*
from
TEMP_TABLE
where
EXISTS (select * from(
select column_value as id 
from table(sys.ku$_vcnt(50,99,150)) 
)
where id
BETWEEN TEMP_TABLE.the_start AND TEMP_TABLE.the_end
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick responses (and to Dems for reformatting my question).

Comment: In this case the list of numbers is not in a table. Is there a way to do this without putting the list of numbers into a different table?

Comment: How are you providing the list of numbers?

Comment: They are coming in as parameters to the method that runs the query.

Comment: So you have 3 integer parameters, and never any more?  Or they're coming in as a string, and the list could be as long as you like?

Comment: I'd prefer not to have to store the numbers in a different table since this query will be call very frequently with different numbers every time. It seems non-optimal to have to continually empty and refill a separate table for every query. But, if that is the only way to do it...

Comment: @Dems It is a comma-delimited list of numbers that could be 1+ numbers long.

Comment: Then your best bet is to look up online a SPLIT function that takes a string and returns a table.  This is not a table that has to be populated and cleared, it's just what the function returns.  You can then use that function in place of the tableList in any of the answers below.

Comment: Thanks Dems. I went ahead and checked your answer since your comment in addition to the below answers gave me the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It partly depends on how your are storing your list of numbers.  I'll assume that they're in another table for now, as even then you have many options.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  yourTable
WHERE
  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM yourList WHERE number BETWEEN yourTable.start_number AND yourTable.end_number)
```

Or...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  yourTable
INNER JOIN
  yourList
    ON yourList.number BETWEEN yourTable.start_number AND yourTable.end_number
```

Both of those are the simplest expressions, and work well for small data sets.  If your list of numbers is relatively small, and your original data is relatively large, however, this may not scale well.  This is because both of the above scan the whole of `yourTable` and then check each record against yourList.

What may be preferable is to scan the list, and then attempt to use indexes to check against the original data.  This would require you to be able to reverse the BETWEEN statement to `yourTable.start_number BETWEEN x and y`

This can only be done if you know the maximum gap between start_number and end_number.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  yourList
INNER JOIN
  yourTable
    ON  yourTable.end_number   >= yourList.number
    AND yourTable.start_number <= yourList.number
    AND yourTable.start_number >= yourList.number - max_gap
```

To achieve this I would store the value of max_gap in another table, and update it as the values in yourTable change.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a full example:

```
create table #list (
number int
)

create table #table (
id int,
start_number int,
end_number int
)

insert into #list values(50)
insert into #list values(99)
insert into #list values(150)


insert into #table values(1,100,200)
insert into #table values(2,151,200)
insert into #table values(3,25,49)
insert into #table values(4,98,99)
insert into #table values(5,49,100)


select distinct a.* from #table a
inner join #list l --your list of numbers  
on l.number between a.start_number and a.end_number


drop table #list
drop table #table
```

---

You'll simply need to remove the code about `#table (create, insert and drop)` and put your `table` in the `select`.

Comment: I wrote almost the exact same using SQL 2008 R2.  The only difference is that I'm not a fan of implicit joins so the FROM clause in mine is FROM #table a CROSS JOIN #list l

Comment: +1, but note: This works and is the simplest expression of the logic.  But it always yields a scan of #table, no matter what indexes you create.  This means that it is great for small data sets, and painful for large data sets.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to create a temporary table to hold your numbers, if the numbers aren't already in one. Then it becomes relatively simple:

```
SELECT DISTINCT mt.ID FROM MyTable mt
INNER JOIN TempTable tt --your list of numbers  
   ON tt.number Between mt.start_number and mt.end_number
```

To create the table based on an array of passed values, you can use table definitions in your procedure. I'm light on Oracle syntax and don't have TOAD handy, but you should be able to get something like this to work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FindIdsFromList
AS
DECLARE
   TYPE NumberRecord IS RECORD (Number int NOT NULL)
   TYPE NumberList IS TABLE OF NumberRecord;
   NumberList myNumberList;
BEGIN
myNumberList := (50,99,150);
SELECT DISTINCT mt.ID FROM MyTable mt
    INNER JOIN myNumberList nt --your list of numbers  
       ON nt.Number Between mt.start_number and mt.end_number
END
```

Comment: +1, but note: This works and is the simplest expression of the logic.  But it always yields a scan of #table, no matter what indexes you create.  This means that it is great for small data sets, and painful for large data sets.

Comment: We're selecting from the main table anyway; that's what the OP needs data from, and so pretty much any algorithm will have to check every row of the main table at least once. It will execute in M*N time time where M is the cardinality of the full table and N is the cardinality of the list. There isn't a really good way to further reduce the complexity of the problem in the general case; you could filter out records in MyTable whose minimums are greater than the largest list value, or whose maximums are less then the lowest. Effeciveness would depend on RANGE(#list).